# how to make OpenAM insert an "Authorization: Basic ..." header

Tags: authentication, basic-authentication, openam

Given a web app (running on a Tomcat server in a secure environment) that does no authentication by itself but trusts any authentication that has happened outside the application and just grabs the principal from the HTTP Basic "Authorization" header to lookup the logged in user, how can OpenAM be configured to set this header after it has handled authentication?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a web app it may look at 'http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser()' or 'http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getUserPrincipal()' instead. These can be set by the J2EE agent. I would say replaying the password (which is base64-encocded within) HTTP Authorization header is not appropriately. If this is really needed then you may have to took at OpenIG.

-Bernhard

Comment: Suppose the web app is changed to use either of those methods, what needs to be done in terms of OpenAM configuration to make sure those are set?  I read in the OpenAM docs: *"**com.sun.identity.agents.config.userid.param**
Agent sets this value for User Id passed in the session from OpenAM to the REMOTE_USER server variable. Default: UserToken."*  Does that mean getRemoteUser() should return the value by default?